# Calling a function from another class in C#/.NET MVC App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create better separation of concerns for code reuse in my program, that way I don't have a bloated controller that does all these different things.

for instance, in my application I have a user profile where users can upload a profile pic. If they don't customize their profile pic, I set the default profile pic to an avatar. I do this through a method to check if their profile pic string is null.

I created a folder called `HelperMethods` and created a class called `UserHelperMethods` which currently has one function:

```
namespace HiRatik.Stories.HelperMethods
{
    public class UserHelperMethods
    {
        //checks if the user's profile pic is null and sets it to default pic if it is
        public string GetUserProfilePic(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            if (user.ProfilePic == null)
            {
                user.ProfilePic = "profile_pic_default.png";
            }

            return user.ProfilePic;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Now, in the controller, under the controller's folder, I added `using HiRatik.Stories.HelperMethods;`

and tried to call the public function `GetUserProfilePic` from the `UserController`. But I'm getting an error on the implementation. I'd like to be able to place a lot of these general functions related to users in another class like `UserHelperMethods` to clean up the bulk in the controller, but I'm missing something on the implementation. the using statement at the top is grayed out, so it's not picking up the function call. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Do you have an instance of that object in your class? `UserHelperMethods helper = new UserHelperMethods()`. Use: `helper.GetUserProfilePic(foundUser)`

Comment: ah. duh!!! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an instance of the helper method class to every class you want to use it in.

```
UserHelpMethods helper = new UserHelperMethods();
```

then you can use it as:

```
helper.GetUserProfilePic(foundUser);
...
help.DoSomethingImportant(foundUser);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to make this into an Extension. Then you will be able to call it like this:

```
user.GetProfilePic();
```

The changes you have to do is, to make both your class and method static and have the *this* keyword before the parameter. Something like

```
public static class ApplicationUserExtensions
    {
        //checks if the user's profile pic is null and sets it to default pic if it is
        public static string GetProfilePic(this ApplicationUser user)
        {
            if (user.ProfilePic == null)
            {
                user.ProfilePic = "profile_pic_default.png";
            }

            return user.ProfilePic;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Depending on the version of C# you are using, you could write the entire method like `return user.ProfilePic ?? "profile_pic_default.png";`

Answer (score 1):

I would consider making these methods static.

```
namespace HiRatik.Stories.HelperMethods
{
    public class UserHelperMethods
    {
        //checks if the user's profile pic is null and sets it to default pic if it is
        public static string GetUserProfilePic(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            if (user.ProfilePic == null)
            {
                user.ProfilePic = "profile_pic_default.png";
            }

            return user.ProfilePic;
        }
    }
}
```

If the helper methods don't rely on any state within the `UserHelperMethods` object, this will make it much easier to call your methods from anywhere, as there is no longer a need to create an instance of the `UserHelperMethods` type. You can call the method like this.

```
UserHelperMethods.GetUserProfilePic(foundUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could update your code to one of the following 
A -

```
namespace HiRatik.Stories.HelperMethods
{
    public class UserHelperMethods
    {
         private static UserHelperMethods _instance = null;
         public static UserHelperMethods Instance()
         {
           if(_instance == null)
           {
             _instance = new UserHelperMethods();
           }
           return _instance;
         }
        //checks if the user's profile pic is null and sets it to default pic if it is
        public string GetUserProfilePic(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            if (user.ProfilePic == null)
            {
                user.ProfilePic = "profile_pic_default.png";
            }

            return user.ProfilePic;
        }
    }
}
```

and inside your Controller just use call it like this

```
UserHelperMethods.Instance().GetUserProfilePic(founduser);
```

Or the easiest way

```
var helperObj = new UserHelperMethods();
helperObj.GetUserProfilePic(founduser);
```

the diff you won't need to create instance all the time in diff controllers

I wish this help you !!

Answer (score 0):

just create instance of the class

```
var myInstance = new UserHelperMethods();
```

then just use `myInstance` object to access the functions in `UserHelpMethods` class

so you can call any function in `UserHelpMethods` like this

```
myInstance.FunctionName();
```

so in your case it will be like

```
myInstance.GetUserProfilePic(foundUser);
```